# How do I send a picture/file from android socket.io client to node.js socket.io server?

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

While chatting I want the user to be able to take a picture and send it to the other chat users. I'm able to get the image but how would I emit it in an optimal manner? Currently I'm encoding the picture in base64 and then decoding it afterwards.

Comment: Sending images over sockets is horrible idea. Horrible. You'll get buffer full of extremely long messages, something that is specifically designed NOT to happen with sockets. Encode and send them over HTTP and then send link in sockets, or something similar. Socket packets should normally be bytes, not hundreds of kilobytes..

Comment: I see, send link as in upload the img to the server first?

Comment: Yeah, use http to serialize and POST the image to the server, which in return gives you url, which you can later send over sockets. It's just that sockets are not designed to send lots of into at once - the data will be separated in different packages and then will be sent at once, which, if happens often, is load on the server..

Comment: If I'm using base64 encoding, do I still need to serialize the image?

Comment: That's kind of serialization :) You can further encode it or compress it (google it). Good luck!